# Visualizing Kinect Output without a TurtleBot

Tags: kinect, rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The "Visualizing TurtleBot Kinect Data" tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data seems very tided to the TurtleBot - is there a way to visualize the Kinect Camera or PointCloud in rviz without the TurtleBot?

Best Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33165/visualizing-kinect-output-without-a-turtlebot/) by [c01e](https://answers.ros.org/users/1442/c01e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-05-03**:
You need some type of URDF so that RViz knows where the Kinect is so it can draw the point clouds. Then you would do what @Ryan says.

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-05-03**:
"roslaunch openni_launch kinect_frames.launch" takes care of setting up some static transforms to let rviz draw the clouds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In three separate terminals, run:

```
roscore
roslaunch openni_launch kinect_frames.launch
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

Then, launch rviz with:

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

Once that's up, select frames (any frames) from the dropdown menus beside "fixed frame" and "target frame". Then, add a PointCloud2 display and select "/camera/depth/points" as its topic. That should display the 3D cloud. You'll probably also want to tweak the display options to make it easier to see (changing from an "intensity" colour transform to an "axis" colour transform, for instance).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2